# When Windows warns you to not turn off your computer...?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consequences of turning off computer during Windows Vista update (“Do not turn off your computer”)?](https://superuser.com/questions/76142/consequences-of-turning-off-computer-during-windows-vista-update-do-not-turn-of)

What will happen if you do?

Sometimes, when I shut down my computer, a screen appears that says something to the effect of "Windows is configuring updates. Do not turn off your computer."

Comment: If you are racing in a car and suddenly would turn off the engine, what would happen?

Comment: If someone tells you not to walk off a cliff and you do. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best case scenario: Nothing

Worst case scenario: A corrupted windows install, or even a corrupted HDD depending on what is being updated at the time

Usually ,windows will self correct the issue at next boot, though your next bootup sequence may be significantly longer than usual

Comment: I wouldn't say usually, your computer will get in an incorrect state and even though there are corrections taking place corruption will most likely occur. At a later moment, one suddenly starts noticing that updates aren't working anymore or whatever has been damaged. This doesn't have to be the same day, but could be the next week or even later in the month. Kind of depends on whether it has been done repetitively.